# How to access Rich Text Field Image outside SalesForce?

Tags: node.js, oauth, salesforce

I'm using `SalesForce` object to store user information, it includes profile image too. I'm able to insert images in Rich Text Field by sending Base64 String along with `<img>` tag. Image gets stored and displayed in the SalesForce page. No problem with that.

Also I'm able to get the image url to the client side (Mobile App) with the help of Rest API (NodeJS).The problem here is, Image URL is accessible(browser) only if the SalesForce account is logged in. If else it goes to the SalesForce login page (When I try with other brower).

What I want is to display the images in my Mobile app which doesn't have SalesForce login access. But I can provide enough information to client side if needed.

My image url looks like this,

https://c.ap5.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a037F00000YSybT&feoid=00N7F00000Pupl6&refid=0EM7F000000lIN0

Also, I have some of the security information in my server side (Node) which I got when I successfully login to SalesForce. BTW I'm using **node-salesforce** package to establish SalesForce connection.

1) organizationId

2) instanceUrl

3) userID

4) accessToken

I have been stuck with this problem since a week before and I'm running out of deadline. **Please HELP!!!**

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find an answer? I am looking for a similar kind of solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Yes, I was able to find the solution. I got support from a SF expert.
There is a way of creating custom domain in SF and map it with url. The url generated by SF will not be availabe outside without login. But using custom domain will make it available. I got my work done.

Comment: Hi JefinOJ. Could you add the details of how you did this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting the urls in the rich text on the fly when returning them from my api. In a manner so that they refer to my api which I use as image proxy through this SF API endpoint with an integration user: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm

```
private void rewriteImageUrls(RichTextRecord richTextRecord) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(richTextRecord.getBody());
    doc.select("img").forEach(imgElement -> {
        try {
            URL originalUrl = new URL(imgElement.absUrl("src"));
            String newUrl = appEnv.getBackendUrl() + "/api/v1/rich_text_records/" + richTextRecord.getSfid() + "/image?refid="+ UrlUtils.getQueryMap(originalUrl.getQuery()).get("refid");
            imgElement.attr("src", newUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    richTextRecord.setBody(doc.outerHtml());
}
```

Far from ideal but it works!